# GoogleCloudSDKInstaller setup failed while installing

Tags: windows, shell, google-cloud-messaging

goolge cloudsdk setup installer failed while installing
Reason : Download failed resolving hostname.
may i know what is the root cause of it

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with this setup. However, are you on a **corporate network** behind a **proxy server** for Internet access?

Checking [the download page for this product](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-windows), it seems they have a page dedicated to this scenario: [**Configuring Cloud SDK for use behind a proxy/firewall**](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/proxy-settings).